# My algorithm never met the requirements to start an Activity?

Tags: java, android

I created an Android game, but it isn't working how it should.

**Main idea**

User clicks `CheckedTextView` three times and after the third click, a second `Activity` is started.

**Problem**

Second `Activity` isn't starting.

[image: ChechedTextView in my app]]

**Code with an algorithm:**

```
public class StartOfTheGame extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.startofthegame);
        Window w = getWindow();
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        final CheckedTextView checkedTextView = findViewById(R.id.checked_textview);
        checkedTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String[] seasons = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};
                int n = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * seasons.length);
                checkedTextView.toggle();
                int a = 0;
                if(checkedTextView.isChecked()) {
                    checkedTextView.setChecked(false);
                    checkedTextView.setText(seasons[n]);
                    a++;
                }
                if (a == 3){
                    try {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(StartOfTheGame.this, SecondStageOfTheGame.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }
            }

        });
```

Comment: where is `a`initialized? When is it initialized?

Comment: You should learn to use a debugger

Comment: Can you [edit] to include a title that actually summarizes your problem? The current one is very generic, which makes it hard for other readers to know whether the question is relevant to them or not.

Comment: Also, please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a` is a local variable. So, everytime you click, `a` is first set to `0` at `int a = 0;`

Try the code below:

```
checkedTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    private int a = 0; // Add this here

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ...
        // int a = 0; // Remove this
        ...
        if (a == 3){
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(StartOfTheGame.this, SecondStageOfTheGame.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```